# How to display a table inside a modal popup window which is part of a larger form

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

I have some code below that contains a form which contains a `hiddenTable` element that will show up once you click the `search` button. My question is: how would I display the table in a modal popup window while still having it be apart of the same form. The table contains a comment box and a submit button, I want the comment to be submitted along with all the other field's data inside the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    #hiddenStuff {
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="...">
    // search fields here
    <input type="button" 
value="Search" 
onclick="document.getElementById('hiddenTable').style.display='block';">

  <table id="hiddenTable" class="form_table" style="display:none;">
    <tr>
      <td class="form_field_name">Enter a comment</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="form_field_entry">
        <textarea required ="true" 
name="textarea" rows="10" 
cols="50" 
placeholder="Please enter a description for the performed task."></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="form_field_entry">
        <cfinput type="submit" name="createPeriod" value="Submit"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Please excuse my messy code.

Comment: You can pass the form fields to the modal popup as url variables, or you can have the modal write back to your main form.  Having said that, if all the modal has is a comment box, why not just have that in them main form?  This seems like a lot of time and effort to achieve an annoying result.

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Dan that it might be a pain for a ux standpoint to make this an extra modal, but if that's the result you want, you can surround your table in a div and add javascript to make the box "popup". Add CSS styles to create the black transparent background on click, and you will have a very simple modal popup.

I created a codepen for a reference -  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/brEHI